# Proof for the equivalence of the convex optimization problem in Kernel Fisher LDA paper.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

All, I am trying to understand the convex optimization move made from eqns. 3 -> eqns. 4 in the [Kernel Fisher LDA paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2000/file/29530de21430b7540ec3f65135f7323c-Paper.pdf). The authors mention that the proof of equivalence is straightforward, and decide that it is too lengthy to present. Could someone help derive this formally and present it here? Thank you very much!

Following @Lutz Lehmann's comment, I attempt to describe the variables and identify the key moves made in the paper. I hope that this makes it easier for us to derive the formal equivalence. Please feel free to correct any errors and make edits for clarity as you see fit.

- Training data: ${x_i: i=1\dots l}$.
- Training labels: ${y_i: i=1\dots l}, y_i\in \{-1,1\}$ corresponding to each of the two classes.
- $\textbf{1}$, vector of all ones. $\textbf{1}_{1}, \textbf{1}_{2}$ binary $(0,1)$ vectors corresponding to the two classes.

1. Standard Fisher LDA solves : $argmax_w \frac{w^T S_B w}{ w^T S_W w }$. Here $S_B=(m_1-m_2)(m_1-m_2)^T$ is the between-class covariance, and $m_k$ the mean feature vector for class $k$. $S_W=\sum_{k=1,2} \sum_{i\in I_k} (x_i -m_k) (x_i-m_k)^T$ is the sum of within-class covariances. $I_k$ indexes the training data for class $k$ .
2. The authors next use the representation $w=\sum_i\alpha_i \Phi(x_i)$, where the Kernel function is defined as $K(x_i, x_j):=\Phi(x_i)^T\Phi(x_j)$. The projection of a test point $x$ onto the discriminant is then represented as: $w^T \Phi(x)=\sum_i \alpha_i K(x_i,x)$.
3. With this representation, we rewrite our objective in terms of $\alpha$:
   $J(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha^T M \alpha}{\alpha^T N \alpha}$, where $M=\mu \mu^T$, $N=KK^T - \sum_{k=1,2}l_k \mu_k \mu_k^T$, with $\mu=\mu_2-\mu_1$, $\mu_k=\frac{1}{l_k}K\textbf{1}_k$.
4. Given that $M$ is rank 1, the authors choose the following normalization for $\alpha$, and rewrite: $argmax_{\alpha} J(\alpha)$,  equivalently as:
   $argmin_{\alpha} \alpha^T N \alpha ~s.t., \alpha^T(\mu_2 -\mu_1)=2$. To this objective, **Eqn. 3** in the paper appends an additional regularizing term $C P(\alpha)$ leading to:

$~~~~~argmin_{\alpha} \alpha^T N \alpha + CP(\alpha) ~s.t., \alpha^T(\mu_2 -\mu_1)=2$

5. Things become less clear to me after this step. The authors write out a convex optimization problem in **Eqn. 4** as:

$~~~~~argmin_{\alpha,\xi, b} ~\xi^T\xi + CP(\alpha) ~s.t., ~K\alpha + b\textbf{1}=y+\xi, \textbf{1}_k^T \xi = 0, k\in\{1,2\}  $. Here $b$ is scalar.

6. Through Proposition 1, the authors claim that Eqns. 3 and 4 (mentioned above in points 4 and 5) are equivalent, and that the formal equivalence proof is straightforward and lengthy. The authors offer some intuition above and below Eqn. 4. I would greatly appreciate any insights you could share! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you just could cite the relevant formulas and a (minimal) description of all occuring variables?

Comment: Thinking about this, these equalities may help: $\textbf{1}=\textbf{1}_1 + \textbf{1}_2$, $\textbf{y}=\textbf{1}_1-\textbf{1}_2$, $\mu_1=\frac{1}{l_1} K \textbf{1}_1 => K\textbf{1}_1=l_1 \mu_1$, $K\textbf{1}_2=l_2\mu_2$, $\textbf{1}^T\textbf{y}=l_1-l_2$, $\textbf{1}^T\textbf{1}=l_1+l_2=l$, $K=K^T$

Comment: Does the following argument to show feasible set for $\alpha$ of Eqn 4 (point 5) same as eqn. 3 (point 4) work? Pre-multiplying the first constraint involving K in eqn. 4 (point 5 above) by $\textbf{1}_1^T$ and  $\textbf{1}_2^T$, and using $\textbf{1}_k^T\xi =0$ for k={1,2}, and $\textbf{y}=\textbf{1}_1-\textbf{1}_2$, yield two equations: $\alpha^T\mu_1+b=1$, and $\alpha^T\mu_2+b=-1$. Subtracting yields constraint $\alpha^T\mu_1 - \alpha^T \mu_2=2$, which is the sole constraint in problem 1.  (Still figuring out the objective.)

Comment: To show that the objective function of eqn. 4(point 5) is the same as eqn. 3 (point 4): We have $\xi=K\alpha + b\textbf{1} - y$ from the first constraint in point 5. Then using $\textbf{1}_k^T\xi=0, ~k=1,2$ yields: $\xi^T\xi=\alpha^T K^T \xi$. Expanding $\alpha^T K^T \xi=\alpha^T[K\alpha + b\textbf{1} - y]$. Using $\textbf{1}=\textbf{1}_1 + \textbf{1}_2$, $y=\textbf{1}_1-\textbf{1}_2$,  $\alpha^T l_1 \mu_1 + b l_1=l_1$, $\alpha^T l_2 \mu_2 + b l_2 = -l_2$, $(b-1)=-\alpha^T\mu_1$, $(b+1)=-\alpha^T\mu_2$, we get $\xi^T\xi=\alpha^T K^T\xi = \alpha^TN\alpha$, same as pnt 4.

Comment: In my previous comment, the equalities $\alpha^T l_1 \mu_1 + b l_1=l_1$ and $\alpha^T l_2 \mu_2 + b l_2=-l_2$ are realized by pre-multiplying the constraint $K$ in eqn. 4 (point 5 above) by $\textbf{1}_1^T$ and $\textbf{1}_2^T$ (same as we did with the constraint set to show that the feasible sets are the same).  In the same way, we get $(b-1)=-\alpha^T\mu_1$ and $(b+1)=-\alpha^T \mu_2$.

Comment: It appears to me that I now have the answer to one direction (point 5 => point 4) in my original question: showing that the objective functions in point (5) and point (4) are the same, and that the feasible set of point (5) is the same as the feasible set of point (4). But, I am seriously amazed at how the authors were able to think about the equivalent problem in point 5 in the first place! From this perspective, a proof in the other direction: (point 4)=>(point 5) would be quite interesting to see! Any takers?! Thanks a lot! And kudos to the original authors!  I love their work!

Comment: I now have the proof for both directions. I will type this up here shortly. Thanks a lot!